# angular 4 - Change form Validators according to selected value

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

i'm using angular Reactive Forms with Form Validations. I would like to create a select input, and only if a specific option is selected ('Other') I want to show additional text input (so user can enter custom answer). 
I made the text input not required by default, then `onValueChanged` i'm checking if option is 'Other' and use `setValidators` to change the input to required.This seem to work, but i'm getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
```

Here is my code:

**component.ts**

```
 buildForm() {
    this.validationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      PaymentMethod: this.formBuilder.control(null, [Validators.required]),
      Package: this.formBuilder.control(null, [Validators.required]),
      CustomAmount: this.formBuilder.control(null, [Validators.min(50), Validators.max(400)]),
    });

    this.validationForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe((data) => this.onValueChanged(data));

    this.onValueChanged(); // (re)set validation messages now
  }

  onValueChanged(data?: any) {
    if (data && data.Package && data.Package.Name === 'Other') {
      console.log('amount should be required now');
      this.validationForm.controls.CustomAmount.setValidators([Validators.min(50), Validators.max(400), Validators.required]);

    }else {
      this.validationForm.controls.CustomAmount.setValidators([Validators.min(50), Validators.max(400)]);
    }
  ...
  }
```

**component.html**

```
 <form [formGroup]="validationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>
        <strong style="display: inline-block; width: 120px;">Payment Method</strong>
        <md-radio-group class="md-radio-group-spacing" formControlName="PaymentMethod" [(ngModel)]="radio.group1">
          <md-radio-button value="Cash">Cash</md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button value="Credit">Credit</md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>
      </p>
      <p>
        <md-select *ngIf="packages" placeholder="Choose Package" formControlName="Package" [(ngModel)]="selectedPackage">
          <md-option *ngFor="let package of packages" [value]="package">
            {{ package.Name }} <span class="blue-500"> {{ package.Price | currency:'USD':true  }}</span>
          </md-option>
        </md-select>
      </p>
      <div *ngIf="selectedPackage" class="callout callout-info">
        <strong>Selected:</strong> {{selectedPackage.Name}}
        <p>{{selectedPackage.Description}}</p>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="selectedPackage && selectedPackage.Name == 'Other'">
        <div class="form-group">
          <md-input-container class="full-width">
            <input type="number" mdInput formControlName="CustomAmount" placeholder="Enter Amount">
          </md-input-container>
          <small *ngIf="formErrors.CustomAmount" class="red-500">
            {{ formErrors.CustomAmount }}
          </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <button md-raised-button type="submit" class="btn-w-md" color="primary" [disabled]="!validationForm.valid">Submit</button>
  <span class="space space-md"></span>
  <button md-raised-button type="button" class="btn-w-md" (click)="dialogRef.close('Cancel')">Cancel</button>
  </form>
```

**edit**
I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188745/angular-2-form-validation-using-validators-with-an-element-that-is-dynamically-b) that is to enable/disable the input. works great! but i'm still happy to hear thoughts and other solutions you think are best. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expression \_\_\_ has changed after it was checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)

Comment: Use `ChangeDetectorRef`, also I strongly suggest you use the form controls instead of `[(ngModel)]`, using `ngModel` is discouraged with reactive forms, and as I have also noticed it can cause problems. So utilize the form controls instead, when you are already using them, `ngModel` is redundant :)

Comment: Thanks @AJT_82 , I didn't realize that it's bad practice to use `ngModel` like that. I will look into `ChangeDetectorRef`

Comment: Yes, `ngModel` directive is not even included in the `ReactiveFormsModule`, so it's clearly not intended to use with reactive forms. So like I said, you can use the form controls, and at the same time get rid of extra variables :) So instead of `selectedPackage.theProperty` you can do... `pathToFormControlHere.value.theProperty` And yes, `changeDetectorRef` will solve your problem (tried it) :)